# My screened in porch with concrete slab for flooring smells like dirty feet at night

Tags: concrete, paint, mold, moisture

I purchased a home that at the time was an open porch with a concrete slab as a floor (painted).

Early in 2021, I had it screened in and wanted to paint the concrete a different color. I stripped/sanded it but at the time in Florida it was too rainy/humid to paint so I furnished it to wait until winter when it is dry.

About mid summer, the porch began to smell like dirty socks. It eventually became unbearable and I began to throw the pillows away, scrub the furniture, etc.

Fast forward to now, I cleaned the cement slab with a floor cleaner before painting which made a difference.

After two coats of paint, the odor is back but with a vengeance. I want to seal it but I’m afraid that I already made a huge mistake with painting it. It only smells at night - any suggestions on how to fix it without ruining the paint?

There are plants around it but I do not smell this odor when outside of the porch. Only inside.

Comment: Add some ventilation.

Comment: Could it be there are animals living under your slab?  Are there tunnels or burrow openings along the edge?  Under a slab is a great place to live.  Dead animal can make a sour smell.  Animal urine can make a sour smell.